# Returning the child of an abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstraction

I've been working on a program for staff management, and currently I have a class (HR), an abstract Employee class, with 2 child classes (Manager and SalesPerson). Currently in the HR function, I have a function that should return a type of employee dependent on the user's input, but currently get the error

```
incompatible types: unexpected return value
```

Here is the code the other classes.

HR (Function snippet, rather than whole class)

```
public Employee createNewEmployee(int index)
{
    switch(index)
            {
                case 0:
                    idTracker++;
                    return new Manager(idTracker, nameField.getText(), Double.parseDouble(salaryField.getText()));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    idTracker++;
                    return new SalesPerson(idTracker, nameField.getText(), Double.parseDouble(salaryField.getText()));
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Didn't work");
            } 
}
```

Employee class

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    protected double salary;
    protected String name;
    protected int IDNumber;
    protected String jobTitle;
    protected String dateEmployed;

    public Employee(int ID, String n, double s)
    {
        IDNumber = ID;
        setName(n);
        setSalary(s);
    }
}
```

And a Salesperson class (manager class is identical, but has a difference in the string jobTitle to show its a manager)

```
public class SalesPerson extends Employee
{
    public SalesPerson(int ID, String n, double s)
    {
        super(ID, n, s);
        jobTitle = "Sales Person";
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you pass in `3`?

Comment: Currently nothing, default kicks in, and displays the input wasn't valid. When I'm using a GUI, it shouldn't be possible to pass in a number not in an index, however I can't get past this bug first.

Comment: That's what *you expect* (or possibly *intend* to happen), not what happens. What happens is that you run off the end of a non-void method without returning a value.

Comment: The errors are compiling on the lines for new Manager, and new SalesPerson, so there's a different issue in there too.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't recompile some classes after changing inheritance patterns.

Comment: All subclasses are compiled. Even removed the default path for now just trying to make sure it's not that there's a path out of place. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any method should always return a value of the declared return type. But there exists in your function `createNewEmployee` an execution path that do not return any value, compiler then tries to emit a simple return, alas this is not compatible with the declared `Employee` type. You can add a `return null` in the default case, for example.

Note that `createNewEmployee` is unusually badly named, *create* implies *new*, then name it `createEmployee` or `newEmployee` (the first is the more usual case).

Comment: Okay, I'll make sure that isn't what's causing the issue and report back. EDIT: The error is coming from the line 
    return new Manager(idTracker, nameField.getText(), Double.parseDouble(salaryField.getText()));

Comment: >Of course it is, another comment says the same... Classical Java programming error.

Comment: Funny, but that isn't the error. The error is compiling on the lines for both new Manager and new SalesPerson.

Comment: Something else is wrong, because that code is correct (up to the return problem).

Answer (score 0):

If the error occurs in one of the lines where a new instance is returned (e.g. `return new Manager(...)`), it might indicate that the `Employee` class expected as the return value is not the same type as the `Employee` class which is extended by the two subclasses `SalesPerson` and `Manager`.

Check the imports in the HR class if the `Employee` return value is the same as the `Employee` class extended by the two subclasses. Maybe you imported an `Employee` class with the same name but from a different package.